# Beginner C++: Strange Behaviour

Tags: c++

thanks for taking the time to read this question!

The program is to find the smallest prime number after one billion. at the end of int main() i included a console input `cin>>x;`with the intention of preventing the command prompt from closing too quickly so i can see the result. however, i realised that i must first enter something before it shows me the result i want.

SO the question is: why is this so even though the console output  statement  `cout<<i;`is before the input statement `cin>>x;`?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

int is_prime(int x);

int main()
{
    for (int i=100000000;;i++){ 
        if(is_prime(i)){ 
                cout<<i;
                break;}
    int x;
    cin>>x;

       }

}

int is_prime(int x)
{
    double maxvalue = sqrt(static_cast<double>(x));
    for ( int i=2;i<=maxvalue;i++){
        if (x%i == 0 ) return false; }
        return true;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> why is this so even though the console output statement `cout<<i;` is before the input statement `cin>>x;`?

Because the `break` changes the order of execution, letting the control skip over `cin >> x` once the prime is found. You need to move the `cin >> x` out of the loop.

There are several things that you can do to optimize things quite a bit: rather than trying to divide by every number `1` through `sqrt(N)`, you should divide out only the prime numbers that you have found so far. This would speed things up a lot. You can also drop the call of `sqrt` by using `i*i < x` as your exit condition.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like the cin >> x is inside the for loop. So, every iteration of the loop, you will try to read something from the stream. So, you need to enter some numbers before the i becomes prime.

EDIT: Apparently, 1000003 is prime, so you don't have to enter a lot of numbers.